# Thread-safety when wrapping unmanaged code

Tags: c#, thread-safety, mutex

Using an API wrapper that contains functions like this

```
  [DllImport("someapi.dll", EntryPoint = "API_Func")]
        public static extern uint ApiFunc(string name);
```

Do I need to use a Mutex if the API itself is thread-safe? I'd say no.

Aside from functions there are just a few static const ints and a few struct declarations.
So on the managed side there shouldn't be any thread-shared resource right?

Comment: The only thing i could think of that may be problematic would be a mutable parameter (in you example string is not) that mutates while marshaling of that parameter into managed space is currently happening when calling a DllImported method.

Comment: @Ralf `string name` will be an `[In]` parameter, so mutations are not expected. An `[Out] out` or `ref` parameter will be copied both ways, so yes the mutation will only be visible on return of the function, and will not be thread-safe unless you manually marshal it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a question which really made me think...

#### My understanding

Since the functions are declared as `static extern`, the functions are not associated with any instance of a class, and there are no instance variables that could be shared among different threads, which could lead to potential race conditions.

As you mentioned, aside from functions, there are just a few `static const ints` and a few `struct` declarations. Since the `consts` and `structs` are not shared resources, there shouldn't be any issues with thread-shared resources on the managed side. The consts are read-only and cannot be modified, so there's no risk of race conditions when accessing them from multiple threads.

#### TL;DR

**If the API documentation states that it is thread-safe**, you can rely on the API to manage thread synchronization internally. In that case, I agree with you, **you don't need to use a Mutex on the managed side**.

Comment: thanks, that were my thoughts too, but I'm not too experienced with this so I don't really trust my judgement ;-)

Comment: All good. I also had to think hard... ;)

Comment: I'm curious what others think about that.